# Add iCloud containers to your App ID - error

Tags: ios, cordova, icloud, phonegap

I am trying to fix this issue for 3 hours now. I have checked the App ID and confirmed the iCloud containers. Also i have entered the same in the app entitlements.

But there is a always a red mark before "Add the “iCloud containers” to your App ID". I created the new provisioning profile and removed the expired provision files also. It was working earlier version of xcode.
Please see screenshot for detail.

Please suggest me.[image]

Comment: Solved! But spent more than a day. Just going to the General tab in Xcode and add an 'x' or whatever to your Bundle Identifier. Go to the Capabilities Tab and the error will have gone from the iCloud. Go back to the General tab and remove the 'x' so the Bundle Identifier is correct again. Go to the Capabilities tab and set the iCloud stuff which will be now error free.

Comment: I don't have any new information to add. I just wanted to reinforce that the posters comment solved the issue for me as well. I added an 'x' to the end of my bundle ID (in the General tab), which caused all sorts of stuff to turn red, then went to the Capabilities tab, back to the General tab, and removed the 'x'. Then I returned to the Capabilities tab and the error message about "Add iCloud Containers to your App ID" was gone.